# why is jquery not picking up my button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my element

```
<input id="0" class="add_to_cart button" type="button" value="Add To Cart">
```

and my jquery

```
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

why doesn't the alert fire when I click the element?

Comment: are you wrapping your javascript code in a document ready function?

Comment: Is your jQuery inside a `$(function() {...});` structure?

Comment: When is the event getting registred ? Before the DOM is loaded ?

Comment: This simple question is going to create 20 questions for clarification.

Comment: no it's not.  So is the issue this isn't wrapped in a document ready function?

Comment: @MattWestlake Yes, most likely.

Comment: please be sure that you add jquery.js file in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your input element is present  in the DOM while binding the event.

You should put your code in document ready event. This is important if you placing your script file (or inline script in your HTML page) above

```
<input id="0" class="add_to_cart button" type="button" value="Add To Cart">
```

Try this

```
$(function(){
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
});
```

Comment: Easy way to check is : alert($(".add_to_cart").length !== 0);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input id="0" class="add_to_cart button" type="button" value="Add To Cart">

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
});
```